# run a bash script from build command of eclipse IDE on windows

Tags: windows, bash, build, eclipse-cdt, stm32cubeide

I have a C/C++ project which is imported to an eclipse based IDE (STM32CubeIDE) on Win 11.
Inorder to compile the project, I have to enter some commands in git-bash. so for simplicity I wrote them into an .sh which is named **build.sh** and put it in the project folder, since then I just need to run this bash like this:
`source build.sh`
in git-bash, and here is its content:

```
#!/bin/sh

source Q:/stm32.sh

cd Q:/dev/my_project

make build_all
```

Right now, I want this script to be called, whenever I press the Build button of the IDE.
I found out that for this I have to change the build command from Propertise->C/C++ Build, uncheck the **use default build command** and then enter the proper command for running the script.
But I could have not do this by now.
I've tried to solve this problem by entering this
`${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/build.sh}`
into the build command, which didn't work.

So my question is that what should I enter here to run the build.sh?
Do you know a better solution for my problem?

Comment: I was under the impression eclipse would find a Makefile if there was one. so this seems over complicated.

Comment: That is indeed a good question, but configuring an IDE does not fit in the forum criteria for asking question this question is better suited for https://superuser.com/

Comment: Have you tried asking about that on https://www.eclipse.org/forums/ ?

Comment: @EricMarceau Yeah, but no answer by now.

Comment: Is **workspace_loc** in "${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/build.sh}" a directory ?  If so, your **${...}** seems to have definitions *which have different scope*.  Namely *"workspace_loc"* seems to imply a **directory**, but  "*/${ProjName}/build.sh*" is clearly a **script**!  To me, that appears to be a bug.

Comment: @EricMarceau But what about this: bash source Q:\dev\evaluation_kit_firmware_test\build.sh It says: Cannot run program "bash source Q:\dev\evaluation_kit_firmware_test\build.sh": Launching failed

Comment: Did you set execution privileges (like unix "read+write+execute", aka rwx) for the script ?  Or do you need to specify "sudo" privileges for the account attempting the execution ?